# Polars: create column from sampling function

Tags: python, python-polars

I am looking to make a new column on a polars data frame.

Suppose I have 2 Lazy Dataframes, `df_1` and `df_2` of different sizes. I want to sample, for each record of `df_2`, a column of `df_1`. In pandas:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "sample_col": list("aabccdeff")
})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "col_1": range(30)
})

rng = np.random.default_rng()
unique = df_1["sample_col"].unique()
df_2["my_sample"] = rng.choice(unique, len(df_2))
```

The unique values are known up front but I'm struggling to move this over to a lazy approach. Pointers?

Edit: updated pandas code

Comment: could you make your example reproducible please?

Answer (score 0):

[`.sample()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.sample.html) exists but needs an integer `n` for the size.

I'm not sure if it's equivalent - but could you assign the list of unique values to each row and use `.shuffle()` to get a random value?

[`.with_context()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.with_context.html#polars.LazyFrame.with_context) is used here to refer to multiple lazyframes "at the same time".

```
(
   df_2
   .with_context(df_1)
   .with_columns(pl.col("sample_col").unique().list())
   .with_row_count()
   .explode("sample_col")
   .select(pl.all().shuffle())
   .groupby("row_nr")
   .agg(pl.all().first())
   .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (30, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr | col_1 | sample_col │
│ ---    | ---   | ---        │
│ u32    | i64   | str        │
╞════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 10     | 10    | e          │
│ 16     | 16    | f          │
│ 5      | 5     | c          │
│ 20     | 20    | b          │
│ 4      | 4     | b          │
│ 13     | 13    | d          │
│ ...    | ...   | ...        │
│ 25     | 25    | f          │
│ 0      | 0     | a          │
│ 2      | 2     | d          │
│ 6      | 6     | a          │
│ 12     | 12    | c          │
│ 14     | 14    | c          │
│ 24     | 24    | d          │
└────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: That's a great idea, I suppose having the extra data is a little inefficient but it works. I didn't go for this in the end but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the following:

```py
distinct_ids = df_1.select([pl.col("DR_NO").unique()]).collect()

q = (
    df_1
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.col("col_1").apply(
                lambda _: distinct_ids.sample(seed=0, with_replacement=True)[0]
            ).alias("my_sample")
        ]
    )
)

q.collect()
```

where `"col_1"` apply keeps track of the 'per row' execution.